# Some questions related to divergence

Tags: inner-products, divergence-theorem

I have some questions about divergence in electromagnetism. Could you answer them for me? I will also attach the image so you can know the meaning of each symbol. Thank you.

2.14 Does ∇.A = 0 at a point in space directly mean A = 0 at the point?
2.18 Is ∇.D useful for checking the presence of a discrete source other than the distributed source or sink? If not, how can you detect a point source?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JW3i.png)

Comment: What is your work on the subject ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, actually I am just learning about it, the subject is called "Introduction to Electromagnetism". I am a chemist and a physics is my weakest point, so I came here to ask.

Comment: Understand that, seen from our side, it looks like you haven't made efforts to answer **any** of these questions. Why don't you say : "on this question, I think that the answer is blah blah ... ? Is it good ? ". Do you want your work entirely done by us without any long term profit for you ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, from what I learned, I think the answer for 2.14 is yes because in order to make ∇.A = 0, the field A must be produced at a point source located at the origin of the coordinate system. About 2.18, I totally have no idea.